# How to configure where Lion fullscreen apps open

Tags: macos, desktop, fullscreen

I recently noticed that when I fullscreen an app, it opens as a new space all the way to the right, after all my desktops. I don't think this is how it worked before -- I seem to recall that it used to open the fullscreen app immediately to the right of my current desktop.

Is there a way to configure this? Where are fullscreen apps opened on most users' operating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at *System Preferences > Mission Control* and see if 'Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use' is checked.

When **checked**, fullscreen windows open to the **immediate right**.

When **unchecked**, fullscreen windows open **at the far right**, after all other desktop spaces.

You can also rearrange desktop spaces by dragging them to the order you prefer in Mission Control.

(I'm running 10.7.3)

Comment: For info, manually reordering spaces and fullscreen apps was added in the 10.7.2 update.